# cordova : add event listener to button when touched

Tags: cordova, events

I am very new to Cordova.. I just try to add an event to a button when it would be touched by the user :

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    receivedEvent: function() {
        ....
        myButtonElement.addEventListener('click', app.authenticationBtnClicked(), false);
    },
    authenticationBtnClicked: function() {
        alert('hello');
    }
}

app.initialize();
```

It does not work.

I tried with those lines too but it did not work more :

```
    myButtonElement.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('salut'); }, false);
    myButtonElement.addEventListener('touchstart', app.authentificationBtnClicked(), false);
    myButtonElement.addEventListener('touchend', app.authentificationBtnClicked(), false);
```

So I decided to forget about javascript addEventLister and put onclick attribute to my html button tag :

```
<button onclick="app.authenticationBtnClicked()">Authenticate</button>
```

It does not work either.

What should I do ?

Ty

Comment: please provide a code pen or fiddle.....and r u getting any errors??

Comment: honestly, I dont know how to get errors display. I am using evothings

Comment: Is that evothings BLE you are using? (Because that's what I'm using)

Comment: evothings BLE ? I dont know. I downloaded it from there https://evothings.com/download/